# Print the third word of each sentence

Tags: perl

```
use warnings;

$reff_filepath="/home/sharma/Documents/ref.txt";
open (CONFIG,"<","$reff_filepath")or die "Unable to open $reff_filepath: $!";

while(<CONFIG>) {
    chomp;
    @cols = (split(/ /))[2];
    push(@array, @cols);
    print "@array\n";
}

close CONFIG;
```

The output I got is:

> On
>   On referendum
>   On referendum Bill
>   On referendum Bill overwhelming
>   On referendum Bill overwhelming claimed
>   On referendum Bill overwhelming claimed Bill
>   On referendum Bill overwhelming claimed Bill governmen

but my expected output is

> On
>   referendum
>   Bill
>   overwhelming
>   claimed
>   Bill
>   governmen

Explaination: I'm trying to print the third word of each sentences using Perl. Above I have written my Perl script. I got that output what I expected in above. But I pushed that output into the array like this `push(@array, @cols)` then i got the first output what I mentioned above. Please anyone will give suggestion or to rewrite the Perl script to display the output I expect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about defining the input separator to "."?

```
$/ = .;

while(<>) {
  $i = 0;
  @words = split(/\s+/);
  while ($i <= $#words) {
     push (@array, @words[$i]);
     $i+=3;
  }
}
print "@array\n";
```

or something similar (I didn't attempt to run this script). You don't attempt to get every third word of each sentence but rather every third word in the entire document.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print **every** third word, just use

```
@cols = grep {not ++$i % 3} (split /\s+/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the array in every iteration of the loop.

You need to move the "print" outside the loop, and also to add a "\n" to each element of the array:

```
push(@array, @cols);

}
print "$_\n" foreach @arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution to print out **every third word from each line** (not sentence) - it will NOT print out empty line where there are less than 3 words:

`perl -e '@a = map { (split /\s+/)[2] } <>; $" = "\n"; print "@a\n";'`

This solution will print empty line where there are less than 3 words:

`perl -e 'print map { (split /\s+/)[2] . "\n" } <>;'`